# Where in iOS 9 Beta 5 is the iTunes Store App?

Tags: iphone, itunes-store, apple-music, ios

Iam a verified developer and have downloaded the latest iOS 9 Beta 5 from https://developer.apple.com/ios/download/.
But my other colleague has same version 9.0 (13A4325c) but he has the iTunes Store app but mine doesn't have a word of mention about the iTunes Store app.

Has it been marinated into Music or is this a bug??

Comment: Did you try searching for "iTunes" via Spotlight?

Comment: Yup searched for iTunes in spotlight and no results, even if I click on an iTunes link it doesn't load iTunes app or do anything

Comment: Did you turn it off under Restrictions? If not, a full restore is probably the best way to move forward

Comment: Restrictions! that did it i forgot that was on! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that Restrictions (Settings > Restrictions > iTunes Store) is enabled.